# MPAndroidChart how can I stop the line when there is no data yet?

Tags: mpandroidchart

I am using MPAndroidLineChart to display some data over the course of a week. This works fine. My problem is this
If, for example, today is Wednesday, I'd like the line chart to abruptly stop at the Wednesday point on the X axis, although the axis goes from Sunday to Saturday. I have attached an example of my current chart[image]

Answer (score 0):

don't set zero value to Thu Fri Sat...But still show X axis Thu Fri Sat

Comment: Hello. I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: I mean you just add four entry not seven!

Answer (score 0):

Loading entry data like this will show a continuous line

```
val entryList: ArrayList<Entry> = ArrayList()
entryList.add(1, 10)
entryList.add(2, 10)
entryList.add(3, 10)
entryList.add(4, 10)
```

Loading entry data like this will show a continuous line

```
val entryList: ArrayList<Entry> = ArrayList()
for (i in 0 until 5){
    entryList.add(i, 10)
}
```

Loading data like this will show a break

```
val entryList: ArrayList<Entry> = ArrayList()
entryList.add(1, 10)
entryList.add(2, 10)
entryList.add(5, 10)
```